# Excel VBA Macro runs fine in debugger but error in full run

Tags: vba, excel, macros

The issue I am running into while running the following code is that when I run the macro in its entirety (by pressing F5, calling it from the button it is assigned to, or running it from the macro bar) I receive:

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.

However, when I run the debugger line-by-line the code runs perfectly fine. In the following code the line that is highlighted during the debugger is outlined in the asteriks "**...code...**" and beings with LastRow.Sheet1.Columns...

The basic premise of this macro is that it is automatically sorting columns to ensure that the entries are at the top of the form control list box I have on another sheet. The second section of code (Below 'PopulateListBox) is meant to pull these data points into the list box.

I would appreciate any assistance you can all provide.

Code:

```
Sub Filter
  Sheet2.Select
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Autofilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Autofilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("K2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
  With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Autofilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
  End With
  Sheet1.Columns("M").ClearContents
  Sheet2.Columns("Z").ClearContents
  Sheet1.Columns("L").Copy
  Sheet1.Columns("M").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  Sheet2.Columns("Z").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  SendKeys ("{ESC}")
  Sheet1.Range("M1") = "Hardcoded Values"
  Sheet2.Range("A1").Select
  'PopulateListBox
  Set lb = Sheet2.Shapes("List Box 1")
  Dim LastRow As Integer
  **LastRow = Sheet1.Columns("M").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues).Row**
  'MsgBox LastRow 'used to verify the above code was working correctly, commented out to speed up process
  lb.ControlFormat.RemoveAllItems
  lb.ControlFormat.ListFillRange = "Z2:Z" & LastRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line?  there is none bolded.

Comment: instead of `SendKeys ("{ESC}")` use `Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Comment: Hi Scott, I apologize. I tried to apply bold to the code but it didn't work. The line in question is near the bottom and begins LastRow.Sheet1.Columns and is outlined by the asteriks (which are not present in the code).

Comment: since you know the column try this instead, `LastRow = Sheet1.Range("M" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for all of the help! Your second suggestion didn't solve the issue, but your first suggestion to move from SendKeys ("{ESC}") to Application.CutCopyMode = False did the trick. I'm not really sure why so if you could explain that would be great! Otherwise, thanks for the suggestion! You saved me a ton of headache.

Answer (score 0):

I can guess that in order to remove a filter, one has to make sure that it already is set in the worksheet. 
If in the worksheet "Data" there is no filter, the line that removes it  will return an error. Therefore, I would suggest inserting an additional line before this line:

```
On Error Resume next
```

Consequently, after "remove filter" line I would write

```
On Error Goto -1
```

Comment: Hi Joanna, Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately that didn't fix the problem. Scott's first suggestion to switch from the sendkeys ("{ESC}") to Application.CutCopyMode=False was the key to fixing it. Not really sure why that helped, but it did!